# What does "AT+CMUX" command do?

Tags: at-command, modem

Hi I'm recently working on a project related to mobile baseband and I found this `AT+CMUX` command.

However I hardly found any references about this, can someone please explain what does it do and what are the benefits of having it?

Comment: Hello, are you using a Telit module?

Comment: I'm voting to reopen because, as stated in this [meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/403258/11336762), questions about AT commands are in topic on SO. Asking _"What is `+CMUX` command for?"_ is just like asking _"What is `strcpy` function for?"_

Comment: No, actually I'm using a custom modem from our company.

Comment: Ok. Very briefly: CMUX is a protocol that allow to multiplex (=mux) the AT serial port into different virtual channels (that will be like having N independent AT instances). By issuing `+CMUX` you activate that protocol, and you won't be able to access the serial port "normally" anymore: you'll need to activate on host side a client able to demutiplex the protocol, so that you'll be able, from your application to access those different AT instances (for example using threads).